# Is Total Error Mean an adequate performance metric for regression models?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression, metrics

I'm working on a regression model and to evaluate the model performance, my boss thinks that we should use this metric:

**Total Absolute Error Mean = mean(y_predicted) / mean(y_true) - 1**

Where mean(y_predicted) is the average of all the predictions and mean(y_true) is the average of all the true values.

I have never seen this metric being used in machine learning before and I convinced him to add Mean Absolute Percentage Error as an alternative, yet even though my model is performing better regarding MAPE, some areas underperform when we look at Total Absolute Error Mean.

My gut feeling is that this metric is wrong in displaying the real accuracy, but I can't seem to understand why.

Is Total Absolute Error Mean a valid performance metric? If not, then why? If it is, why would a regression model's accuracy increase in terms of MAPE, but not in terms of Total Absolute Error Mean?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I really am questioning the formula for the total absolute error mean. Do you have any sources or how did you derive it? In my opinion, it does not make that much sense to compute the mean of the prediction alone. Usually you would compute the mean over the difference (y_predicted - y_true). This metric is also called Mean Absolute Error and is one of the most basic ones.

Comment: Edited my original question - they are not a single value, but a list of values - the formula compares the average of y_true versus the average of y_predicted. The formula is something that he had measured for his model before I started working, so I'm guessing that was his idea.

Comment: I already, thought of it as a list of values, but I don't see the point of doing an overall average. I would instead as said use the more classic MAE loss function.

Comment: I agree, but how would I convince my boss to drop this metric? Why is it pointless to use a total average as a supporting metric alongside MAE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would kindly suggest to inform your boss that, when one wishes to introduce a new metric, it is on him/her to demonstrate why it is useful on top of the existing ones, *not* the other way around (i.e. us demonstrating why it is not); BTW, this is exactly the standard procedure when someone *really* comes up with a new proposed metric in a research paper, like the recent proposal of the [Maximal Information Coefficient (MIC)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3325791/).

That said, it is not difficult to demonstrate in practice that this proposed metric is a **poor** one with some dummy data:

```python
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# your proposed metric:
def taem(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.mean(y_true)/np.mean(y_pred)-1

# dummy true data:
y_true = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Now, suppose that we have a really awesome model, which predicts perfectly, i.e. `y_pred1 = y_true`; in this case both MSE and your proposed TAEM will indeed be 0:

```python
y_pred1 = y_true # PERFECT predictions
mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred1)
# 0.0
taem(y_true, y_pred1)
# 0.0
```

So far so good. But let's now consider the output of a *really bad* model, which predicts high values when it should have predicted low ones, and vice versa; in other words, consider a different set of predictions:

```python
y_pred2 = np.array([6,5,4,3,2,1,0])
```

which is actually `y_pred1` in reverse order. Now, it easy to see that here we will also have a perfect TAEM score:

```python
taem(y_true, y_pred2)
# 0.0
```

while of course MSE would have warned us that we are very far indeed from perfect predictions:

```python
mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred2)
# 16.0
```

**Bottom line**: *Any* metric that ignores element-wise differences in favor of only averages suffers from similar limitations, namely taking identical values for any permutation of the predictions, a characteristic which is highly undesirable for a useful performance metric.

Comment: "when one wishes to introduce a new metric, it is on him/her to demonstrate why it is useful on top of the existing ones, not the other way around". These are my thoughts exactly! 

Thank you very much, I will consider a good approach to explain this to him!